# How do you set up test data to work with Calabash and Cucumber-Rails

Tags: android, postgresql, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-4.2, calabash

I am working with Rails 4.2.5, Cucumber-Rails 1.4.3 and Calabash-Android 0.7.2 with Postgres (pg 0.18.4).
I am trying to set up the testing environment for my project.
I have set up the Database Cleaner strategy to be :truncation.
I have also set Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false.

I am creating some data for the test in the Background of the Cucumber feature. However, when I run my test for an Android device using Genymotion, the data set up by the Background is not returned to the Android application.

If I create the same data before running the test then the data is returned successfully. So it seems that the data created as part of the test by Cucumber is not visible to the application for some reason even though it should have been committed.

Does anyone have any insight as to why the data created as part of the Cucumber scenario is not available to the test (as I have done a million times in "standard Rails")?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was that the Android app was loading and accessing the database BEFORE my Background steps had run to populate the table.

I needed to ensure that an action was taken to cause the data to load AFTER the application was initialised.

Nothing to do with database cleaner strategy in the end.